# Problem making a discord reaction role bot in discord

Tags: discord.py

So im currently making a discord bot that give a specific role to who ever react to the message i encountered some problems i can't fix my self

```
   @client.event
    async def on_ready():
            Channel = client.get_channel('904620745462804520')
            Text= "React to get Verified!"
            Moji = await client.send_message(Channel, Text)
            await client.add_reaction(Moji, emoji='✅')
    @client.event
    async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
            Channel = client.get_channel('904620745462804520')
            if reaction.message.channel.id != Channel:
                    return
            if reaction.emoji == "✅":
                  Role = discord.utils.get(user.server.roles, name="Verified")
                  await client.add_roles(user, Role)
```

Comment: Please share information about what problems you are encountering in your question. It will make it easier for people to provide useful answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, read [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html) carefully

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    Channel = client.get_channel('904620745462804520')
    Text = "React to get Verified!"
    Moji = await Channel.send(Text)
    await Moji.add_reaction(emoji='✅')


@client.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
    if reaction.message.channel.id != '904620745462804520' or user == client.user:
        return
    if reaction.emoji == "✅":
        guild = await client.fetch_guild('GUILD_ID_HERE')
        Role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="Verified")
        await user.add_roles(Role)
```